# Unable to install pear dependancy - Log

Tags: php, pear

ran:

> pear install Log

got:

> No releases available for package "pear.php.net/Log"
>
> install failed

Tried to go to their website (http://pear.php.net/package/Log/) and get a 404.

Comment: You should check their [main page](http://pear.php.net/) aswell next time.

Comment: PEAR website is currently down due to a security issue.

Comment: Hah! I honestly didn't investigate any further. I just wanted to get my stuff up and running and really hadn't considered why it wasn't working. I had installed phing/phing before and unless i glazed over the details. We can delete this post if it isn't useful. I just wanted to share how I got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Go to: https://github.com/pear/Log/releases

Download the latest release in .tgz format. (for me it was 1.13.1)

run: pear install \PATH\To\FILE\Log-1.13.1.tgz